# Remove the dot before pages in the table of content entries in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm having a hard time removing the dots before the pages in the table of content entries in LibreOffice.

The automatically generated table of content from Headings results in the following:

```
1. Name ..............  .1
1.1. SubName .........  .3
1.2. OtherSubName ....  .5
1. OtherName .........  .6
```

I have tested/looked around the options for the TOC, but was unable to find a solution. This dot can be remove from TOC options/entries/structure/T/Fill Character, but that removes all filling dots, which I want to keep, just the prefix of the page I want to remove. Please help.

ps. It might be something related to the font size, because the empty space before the .# is different visually, just the last dot is placed properly.

ps2. After some experimentation, I'm starting to suspect that this is a bug in the filling algorithm.